# Write conclusion

Tags: statistics, soft-question

How can i write finding and conclusion after caculating the result of standard deviation? I can caculate the standard deviation question properly, but i can't write the finding on this question. I mean, eg. I get the result of mean value is 35. The standard variation value are 17 and 6 separately.

Comment: "The standard variation value are 17 and 6 separately", what do you mean?

Comment: A test lab whishes to test two experimental brands of outdoor paint to see how long each will last before fading. The two brand are shown. Brand A- 10,60,50,30,40,20. Brand B - 35,45,30,35,40,25.Mean value is 35 and I can find its standard deviation are 17 and 6. How can i make a conclusion on my finding of them.

Comment: Please include your last comment on the question in order to improve your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to report them separately, use the method below:

$x=\bar x \pm s$

Where: $\bar x$ is mean and $s$ is the standard deviation.

- For the first data set, as $\bar x=35$ and $s=17$, then: $x=35 \pm 17$
- For the second data set, as $\bar x=35$ and $s=6$, then: $x=35 \pm 6$

But if you want to combine all results and report only one $x$, then you should use the method @Remy mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the population variances are the same, you can find the pooled sample standard deviation as follows:

$$s_{pooled}=\sqrt\frac{(n_1-1) s_1^2+(n_2-1) s_2^2}{n_1+n_2-2} $$

where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the number of observations in populations $1$ and $2$, respectively.

In this case, our degrees of freedom becomes $$df=n_1+n_2-2$$

Under the assumption that the population variances are not the same, you can find the unpooled sample standard deviation as follows

$$s_{unpooled}=\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}}$$

but this makes $$df=\frac{\left(\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}\right)^2}{\frac{1}{n_1-1}\left(\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}\right)^2+\frac{1}{n_2-1}\left(\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}\right)^2}$$

Comment: Remy, here Tie said: "A test lab wishes to test two experimental brands of outdoor paint to see how long each will last before fading", I guess we need to report 2 separate $x$s in order to compare, don't we?

Comment: Yes, after re-reading that, I think you are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not clear enough anyway...

Comment: I can't understand clearly to use brand A or B.